# sqlite db which created by db browser does not work in android studio

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, db-browser-sqlite

I have created an SQLite database using DB Browser, when I move it to the assets folder and open it in the android studio it looks so bad and it doesn`t work. what is the solution ? :(

here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCvRk.png)

Comment: why you want to open it? to see data?

Comment: No, just because the application stopped when I tried to query the database. so I found that the problem is in the database (look at the screen shot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the screen shot pretty much confirms that the file in the asset folder is a valid SQLite database.

That is the first 16 bytes match those of the database header **The header string: "SQLite format 3\000"** [Database File Format](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#database_header).

Android Studio itself does not include the requirements to actaully open the file as an SQLite Database (there are tools, such as DB Browser that do this).

What you need to do, with your App, is open the file as an SQLiteDatabase. This is normally accomplished by copying the file from the asset folder to a suitable location (as the asset folder is part of the package it is read only) and then opening it from that location often via a subclass of the SQLiteOpenHelper.

There is a class available, namely [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), that can make opening the database relatively easy. **Note** that SQLiteAssetHelper expects the database (name same as the file name including extension) to be in the **databases** folder of the assets folder (you would likely have to create this folder, although the screenshot shows that you have aleady placed the database into the databases folder).

### Example

The following is a quick example of using the SQliteAssethelper to open the database and in this case list the items (tables, views, indexes, trigger etc) as per sqlite_master (SQlite's master table).

**Build.gradle** (App) (part thereof) :-

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+' //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED JUST THIS LINE
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

- **See comment re added line**

The DatabaseHelper (subclass of SQLiteAssethelper) **DBHelper.java**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "DaycareCenters.db";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }
}
```

An invoking Activity (as an example) **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper mDBHlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);
        Cursor csr = mDBHlpr.mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master",null);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("SQLITEMASTER","Name = " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("name")) + " Type = " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("type")));
        }
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

### Result (written to the Log)

- Note I just copied a database that was convenient to copy, the tables etc list will not be the same as yours.

.

```
12-09 09:55:19.760 1473-1473/? I/SQLiteAssetHelper: successfully opened database DaycareCenters.db
12-09 09:55:19.764 1473-1473/? D/SQLITEMASTER: Name = android_metadata Type = table
12-09 09:55:19.764 1473-1473/? D/SQLITEMASTER: Name = player_card Type = table
12-09 09:55:19.764 1473-1473/? D/SQLITEMASTER: Name = sqlite_autoindex_player_card_1 Type = index
12-09 09:55:19.764 1473-1473/? D/SQLITEMASTER: Name = email Type = table
12-09 09:55:19.764 1473-1473/? D/SQLITEMASTER: Name = region Type = table
12-09 09:55:19.764 1473-1473/? D/SQLITEMASTER: Name = card Type = table
12-09 09:55:19.764 1473-1473/? D/SQLITEMASTER: Name = pc Type = table
12-09 09:55:19.764 1473-1473/? D/SQLITEMASTER: Name = sqlite_autoindex_pc_1 Type = index
```

- First line is from the SQliteAssetHelper - it confirms that the database was copied from the assets folder.
- The 2nd line shows table android_metadata, this is an android specific table that will be added, it contains the locale.
- A few other tables.
- A few indexes that are automatically created because of constraints or implied constraints
- In short all is as expected.

Comment: where Log? to see the result

Comment: why the application stopped when I tried to query the database :(

Comment: In Android Studio click on **Logcat** near the bottom.There are numerous reason why a query may not work (again the logcat should say why). You should really ask another question (especially if you used the above and the tables etc were listed in the logcat, as this answers you initial question, in which case you should tick the question as answered).